# getting NSString Array index by value in objective C

Tags: objective-c

I am new to objective C. I have created an NSString array by the following way:

```
static NSString* fontSizeName[] = 
{
 @"14",
 @"18",
 @"22",
 @"26",
 @"30",
 @"34",
};
```

Now, i have the value, "26", how can i get the index of it in fontSizeName[]?

Thanks for input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *val = @"26";    // Get this from somewhere
int i;
int idx = -1;
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    if ([fontSizeName isEqualToString:val]) {
        idx = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 A "nil" sentinel element in the array would make it more flexible though and wouldn't need to hardcode the length. Or use an NSArray instead with indexOfObject:.

Comment: @Eiko: I think you should make the NSArray part an answer.  I was going to until I saw your comment.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `indexOfObject` method:

```
index = [fontSizeName indexOfObject:@"26"];
```

Comment: That would be great if `fontSizeName` was an `NSArray`, but it's an ordinary C array.